# Animate all rendered views in Marionette?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

In marionette version v1.0.0-rc3 source code line 1222 I have:

```
var template = this.getTemplate();
var html = Marionette.Renderer.render(template, data);
this.$el.html(html);
```

I am trying to animate all rendered views by overriding this part of the framework.
I have the following code so far but I do not know if this can be possible.

```
//this.fadeIn(template, this.$el);
//this.$el.animate(html);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did the following:

```
this.$el.html(html).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Add ".hide()" before ".fadeIn()"